# Item ID’s given by Office JS object are different for Outlook App and web

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

We developed Outlook addin using the framework provided by Office JS.
We observed following differences in Item IDs in web and outlook app.

Please see the following ID's. "Separator is different". How we will identify the uniqueness of emails.

e.g.,

```
Web :AQMkAGI5MTEANDkzYi1mYTJlLTQwNDUtOGI1Ni00ODJmODc0N2M3NjIARgAAA5vnUELrbT5Mp3SvmLMR6MEHAP7qKD1uxMdCtoUAa/H6RZsAAAIBDAAAAP7qKD1uxMdCtoUAa/H6RZsAAAIXmAAAAA==
App :AQMkAGI5MTEANDkzYi1mYTJlLTQwNDUtOGI1Ni00ODJmODc0N2M3NjIARgAAA5vnUELrbT5Mp3SvmLMR6MEHAP7qKD1uxMdCtoUAa-H6RZsAAAIBDAAAAP7qKD1uxMdCtoUAa-H6RZsAAAIXmAAAAA==
```

Comment: when you say "outlook app" are you referring to mobile app or the desktop client?

Answer (score 0):

Different Outlook clients will return the itemId in the protocol they leverage. REST and EWS itemIds are escaped differently which is causing the difference between the itemId for the same item. To convert an EWS itemId to REST you can leverage the [convertToRestId](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5#converttorestiditemid-restversion--string) JS API.